# Android 4.4.2 Bluetooth Icon is grey even though device is connected

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am using the Android BLE stack and despite obtaining a programmatic connection with a BLE device, the Android Bluetooth status icon appears grey as if nothing is connected.

My theory is that when you pair/bond via code only (I know the BT Address of all devices before connecting) that the connection indicator does not light up white as the user was not directly involved in the process.

I was unable to find anyone else indicating they have the same issue.

---

**Logical steps in my code.**

1. BT on, BT icon is grey.
2. Device connected via USB; Bluetooth Address is read from device and instructed to be ready for BT connection.
3. BT LE scan is started looking for device Address.
4. Device is paired and bonded programmatically. BT LE scan is stopped.
5. Data is exchanged between devices verifying communication.
6. User is now able to talk to the device and device is able to talk back when it has information for the user.
7. BT icon is still grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start developing BLE on Android since the very first day since 4.3 release, and have never seen the bluetooth icon light up. I am not familiar with classic Bluetooth development, so I just asked my colleague to pair my phone and send some file via classic bluetooth - the icon also didn't light up. May be you mix up the behaviour with the one on iOS ?

Comment: I suppose its possible it never lights up but I would swear that when I had my Pebble, it showed white while connected/in range.

Comment: I am unable to find anything that suggests otherwise to what you stated so I am going to assume you are correct about this.